# Problems with Applescript and Automator after macOS update

Tags: applescript

I had an Automator app that was working perfectly.
I use it to open Safari and fill a form with data taken from a numbers document.

To select the input fields I use something like:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('Name').value = '" & name & "';
```

But as soon as the app gets to that line, it encounters an error and stops. I tried several other commands using `do JavaScript` but nothing seems to work.

I'm not sure if this issue is related to the update. Could the `do JavaScript` command change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In Safari, I needed to enable scripts from Apple Events. This option was disabled with the update.

The error didn't display any kind of information, it only said the the application found an error and needed to stop. So it was hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Do JavaScript has to address a tab in a Safari window

```
tell application "Safari" 
    activate 
    set jScript to "yourscriptcode;"
    do JavaScript jScript in current tab of first window 
end tell
```

Comment: No, I still get the error. It's like applescript isn't letting me use any kind of javascript.

Comment: whats the exact error? paste the html (essential part)